# How to selectively choose facet_wrap() combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, regression

I have a data frame with water quality information on 20 lakes. For each lake the ph and dissolved oxygen levels were measured multiple times per visit, and the mean and max values recorded in the data frame. Model-derived estimates for dissolved oxygen and ph were calculated separately using two different methods. I would like to make a figure with 4 panels of scatterplots depicting the relationships between the observed values and the estimated values for each estimation "method" and water quality parameter. I would like to avoid using methods like `ggarrange()` as I have a custom theme I am using that would require a lot of extra work. My best idea is to use `facet_wrap()` in `ggplot()`, but this yields all possible combinations of the different variables, and I am only interested in 4 specific combinations.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

#creating a dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  method = c(rep("quad", 10), rep("linear",10)),
  date = c(rep("2021-11-17", 10), 
           rep("2022-02-27", 5),
           rep("2021-11-20",5)),
  ph_est = rnorm(20, 3),
  disso_est = rnorm(20, 1),
  mean_ph = rnorm(20, 0),
  max_ph = rnorm(20, 2),
  mean_disso = rnorm(20, 5),
  max_disso = rnorm(20, 10)
)
df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))
```

```
#pivoting longer in order to plot
df_l <- pivot_longer(df,
  cols = c("ph_est", "disso_est"),
               names_to = "samp_pars",
               values_to = "samp_vals")
df_l <- pivot_longer(df_l, cols = c("mean_ph", "max_ph", "mean_disso", "max_disso"),
               names_to = "est_pars",
               values_to = "est_vals")
```

```
#Attempting the plot
ggplot(df_l, aes(x = est_vals, y = samp_vals)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ method + samp_pars + est_pars, scales = "free")
```

The output is close, but I only want 4 panels:

1."**quad**" method for **estimated ph** vs **mean** ph

2."**quad**" method for **estimated** DO vs **mean** DO

3."**linear**" method for **estimated** ph vs **max** ph

4."**linear**" method for **estimated** DO vs **mean** DO

Is there a way I can rearrange my data frame to make this work? or do I need to go about this whole thing differently?

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are looking for `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` [docs](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/facet_wrap_paginate.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! can you explain a little more please? From the documentation it seems ```ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate``` would be helpful to split the panels over multiple pages, but how would I then be able to choose which panels are in the same page?

Comment: shaun_m answer works. In any case, you can combine `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate` and `ggforce::n_pages(q)` to extract all individual facets and recombine the relevant ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the data frame to keep only the combinations you require for the 4 plots.

Add the following before your `ggplot` :

```
df_l <- filter(df_l,
               (method=="quad" & samp_pars=="ph_est" & est_pars=="mean_ph") |
                 (method=="quad" & samp_pars=="disso_est" & est_pars=="mean_disso") |
                 (method=="linear" & samp_pars=="ph_est" & est_pars=="max_ph") |
                 (method=="linear" & samp_pars=="disso_est" & est_pars=="mean_disso") 
               )
```

Then the `ggplot` will only output the 4 plots you require.

Comment: Beautiful this works great thank you! It seems like the answer to any ggplot question is to subset the dataframe first.